# The compiler error "> error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token" when using boost

Tags: c++, boost

When I am using Boost for the first time, and trying to compile my first code using `<boost/regex.hpp>`

I got the following compiler error

`/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits_defaults.hpp:289: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token`

Going to the .hpp code, I found the line 289 like

`static const charT A = 'A';`

It seems that my compiler doesn't allow A as variable name.

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 under Linux Red Hat 5.8

Comment: By convention uppercase is for macros. Maybe A is a macro.

Comment: ...which would be a spectacularly bad idea. But yes, this sounds like a macro issue.

Comment: preprocess the source. Or find the place where you said `#define A` and fix it :)